# debezium w/o Kafka dependency

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-pubsub, debezium, connector

I am trying to configure debezium v2.0.0 with Oracle connector using Kafka-less approach, following similar configuration to: https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/u_-Yu9py3ss

I am getting this error when I start it:

> ERROR [io.deb.sto.kaf.his.KafkaSchemaHistory] (pool-7-thread-1) The
> 'schema.history.internal.kafka.topic' value is invalid: A value is
> required

> ERROR [io.deb.sto.kaf.his.KafkaSchemaHistory]
> (pool-7-thread-1) The
> 'schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers' value is invalid: A
> value is required

Is there way to disable this (I am not interested in capturing schema changes) or reconfigure to keep schema history in Pub/Sub rather than Kafka? Referring documentation for this didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Use these parameters to point to a File based source for schema history.

```
debezium.source.schema.history.internal=io.debezium.storage.file.history.FileSchemaHistory
debezium.source.schema.history.internal.file.filename=data/schema_history.dat
```

Comment: Where these parameters should be set?